# What's wrong with `find-file-noselect`?

Tags: files

In a recent [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/145/what-are-some-built-in-packages-with-nice-source-code/151#151) by [lunaryorn](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/227/lunaryorn), he stated:

> However, I'd recommend against most other parts of Org, for reasons
>   already stated in comments: It's old, and full of legacy and harmful
>   practices (e.g. find-file-noselect to read files non-interactively).

Can anyone explain why is `find-file-noselect` a bad idea to read files in Elisp programs? Is there a better way? I'm asking because I was thinking of using it in one of my projects.

Comment: Seemingly, there was no `good-practices` tag before; is it a good idea to use it?

Comment: I think that `good-practices` would fall under the category of "meta tag," which is [frowned upon](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) by SE.

Comment: @nispio I think it's a valid tag, but we can take this to the meta of course.

Comment: @nsipio: I've skimmed through that article, and I don't agree.  But it's not me who decides. ;-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**TL;DR**: With `find-file-noselect` you have **no control** about what actually happens, and you may end up with arbitrary minor modes enabling in the buffer, depending on what the user enabled in their `init.el`.  Also, cleanup is hard.

Use `with-temp-buffer` and `insert-file-contents` instead.  If you need specific major or minor modes in the buffer, enable them **explicitly**.  To write files, use `with-temp-file` instead, which—despite its name—lets you write to arbitrary files.

## Side effects

`find-file-noselect` has **a lot** of side-effects, including

- interactively asking questions (that alone is a no-go in non-interactive use),
- automatically enabling view mode for readonly files,
- entering normal mode otherwise,
- and running `find-file-hook`.

Normal Mode itself

- automatically selects a proper major mode for the current buffer,
- runs all corresponding major and minor mode hooks,
- and reads all local variables for the current buffer, i.e. file variables and directory variables, which again may ask interactive questions about unsafe local variables.

Since all hooks are run, you get **all minor modes and hook functions** the user enabled in their `init.el`, which can cause everything, from minor inconveniences (if undesirable minor modes are enabled) to major havoc (if the user added a hook function that expects to be called from an interactive context).

See https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/366 for an example.  The use of `find-file-noselect` caused a data file to be syntax-checked by Flycheck, and since it was happening at Emacs shut-down, there was no time to properly clean up again, leaving a temporary file behind.

## Cleanup

With `find-file-noselect` you need to be extra careful to kill the buffer again.  `find-file-noselect` does not do that for you.

You need to remember the buffer at some place, and carefully use `unwind-protect` to make sure that the buffer gets killed even in case of non-local exits.

## Alternatives

To read files, use `with-temp-buffer` and `insert-file-contents`, which only does the most basic things, e.g. coding system conversion, but does not ask questions, enable hooks, or setup local variables:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert-file-contents (locate-user-emacs-file "foo.el"))
  ;; Enter the major mode explicitly
  (emacs-lisp-mode)
  ;; …
  )
```

`with-temp-buffer` takes care to properly kill the temporary buffer at the end of its body.

To write files, use `with-temp-file`, which creates a temporary buffer and writes the contents to the given file name at the end of its body:

```
(with-temp-file  (locate-user-emacs-file "foo.el")
  (prin1 (list 'my 'data) (current-buffer)))
```

Answer (score 10):

From section 24.3 in the Elisp manual:

> To copy the contents of a file into a buffer, use the function
>   `insert-file-contents`.  (Don't use the command `insert-file` in a
>   Lisp program, as that sets the mark.)

Searching the Elisp documentation for `find-file-noselect` it is obvious that it does much more than just reading a file into a buffer. Perhaps people who think using this function is a bad idea are thinking about the, possibly unwanted, side-effects? I guess it depends on what you want to achieve. If you want to have as clean/untouched buffer content as possible, it might be a good idea to use the old and trusty `with-temp-buffer` + `insert-file-contents`combination. If you want the buffer contents to be as close to what `find-file` produce, perhaps you *do* want to use `find-file-noselect`? Or perhaps he was thinking about `find-file` ;)

Comment: If something is being done non-interactively I can't see any scenario in which you'd want *" the buffer contents to be close to what find-file would produce"*. find-file is slow because it does a ton of unnecessary stuff, including all sorts of hooks. The only "feature" of find-file which you might want is the major-mode, but then you should just activate it yourself (you can't even guarantee find-file would turn on the mode that you want anyway).

Comment: Malabarba: If you intend for the buffer to remain available for editing by the user, then you may very well want to mimic the `find-file` process.