# find-file-hook but only if file is selected

Tags: hooks, find-file

This is pretty simple, I'm trying to find (or build) a hook that fires when files are visited *and* selected (i.e. immediately displayed).

## Background

I'm writing a UI centric entry for `find-file-hook`, but it turns out that `find-file-hook` is fired for all sorts of things that I don't need:

- Semantic assets which are loaded when semantic starts
- Files opened in the background for my on-the-fly diffing program
- Probably other stuff, that's all I could think of off the top of my head

Most of this is done by way of `find-file-noselect`, which associates a buffer with a file, but does not `switch-to-buffer` on the newly created buffer like `find-file` does.

I would like my hook to execute only when the current buffer changes.

Comment: What do you mean by "*selected*" ("*not by `find-file-noselect`*")? Do you mean displayed?

Comment: Essentially. `find-file-noselect` finds the file but does not display it (the documentation calls it "selecting" a file?)

Comment: Are you interested in adding a hook to one of the functions in `files.el` or in `window.el`, or something else?  Consider adding a specific example so that forum participants have a better idea of what you are seeking.

Comment: `find-file-noselect` ensures that a buffer has the contents of a file. *Buffers are visited, not files.* If a buffer already has the file contents in it then that buffer is returned (the buffer contents are also checked wrt the file on disk, and you are alerted if they are out of sync). So a file being "*visited and selected*" doesn't mean much (to me anyway). When `find-file-noselect` returns a buffer that is visiting the file, I guess that is what you mean by "*visited and selected*", but then you add "*(i.e., **not** by `find-file-noselect`)*". So it's unclear to me what you mean.

Comment: @lawlist I'd expect something like that would be the only solution.

Comment: @Drew Does the newly edited question make more sense?

Comment: I guess so. It's certainly different from before anyway. Do you mean visited *or* displayed, perhaps? If not, I would think that just displayed covers *and* - a file buffer cannot be displayed without visiting the buffer. Besides this, I guess it's still not clear to me what you are asking. I wonder if you are looking for what file handlers offer, perhaps. Anyway, hopefully someone else will understand the question and answer it usefully.

Answer (score 2):

At the point where `find-file-hook` is called the buffer is not yet displayed in either case, and you don't know yet whether it's going to be shown in a window or not.  You could hook into `window-configuration-change-hook`, but that in turn does not tell you whether the buffer was selected immediately in `find-file`, or at some arbitrary later point.

Your best chance to work around these issues is a multi-step process:

1. In your `find-file-hook`, remember the value of `this-command` in a buffer-local variable, and add a local `window-configuration-change-hook`.
2. In that hook, check whether the buffer has a window with `(get-buffer-window)`.

If it does, and `this-command` is still the same as you remembered, there's a good chance that finding the file and showing the buffer came from the same command, i.e. `find-file` or some variants thereof, and you can start your UI.  If `this-command` has changed without the buffer having a window, however, it was obviously not `find-file`, and you can remove your hook from `window-configuration-change-hook` without starting your UI.

That is complicated, for sure, but it's the only way I can think of to work around broken packages which abuse `find-file-noselect` to load internal assets and data files.  You [should never do that](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/whats-wrong-with-find-file-noselect).  If you care, please report these issues to developers whenever you spot them.  `find-file` is only for interactive use.

Comment: Sorry, It's going to be a while before I can test this. Please hang in there :)

Answer (score -2):

```
(advice-add 'find-file :after
            (lambda (&rest _args)
              (message "Called after `find-file' but not `find-file-no-select'")))
```

Comment: Please add more to this answer to give context and better flesh out the answer.

Comment: @Finding Nemo, this is not as powerful as `find-file-hook` because other functions (e.g. `ido-find-file`) call `find-file-hook`, but do not use `find-file`. I don't want to manually collect a list of such functions, hence this question.